# CSS and the jQuery animate() function are creating space at the wrong side

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the .animate() function (which Ive marked in bold) to slide a series of divisions right-to-left, which is working. However, I can't scroll backwards to the left, since it appears that width to left that would hold the divisions has been placed to the right, which is effectively empty space.

Here's the CSS:

```
div.folders-hierarchy {
    border: 1px dotted #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 325px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}

div.folders-hierarchy .container-folders {
    right: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 0px;
}

div.folders-hierarchy .container-folders .container-folder {
    float: left;
    width: 325px;
}

div.folders-hierarchy ul {
    margin: 0 5px;
    width: 315px;
}

div.folders-hierarchy ul input[type="radio"] {
    margin: 0 2px;
}

div.folders-hierarchy ul li {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="folders-hierarchy">
    <div class="container-folders"></div>
</div>
```

And here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var folders = new Object();
    var levels = new Object();
    var id;
    var container = 325;
    var slide = 0;
    levels.index = 0;
    folders.chosen = (folders.chosen == null) ? 0 : folders.chosen;
    $(".folders-hierarchy").delegate('li a', 'click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        id = parseInt($(this).attr("data-folder"));
        levels.chosen = parseInt($(this).closest('ul').attr("data-levels"));
        folders.chosen = id;
        if (levels.chosen < levels.index) {
            if (levels.index > 1) {
                x = (levels.index+1);
                for (var i=0;i<x;i++) {
                    if (i > levels.chosen) {
                        $('[data-levels="' + i + '"]').parent().remove();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $('[data-levels="1"]').parent().remove();
            }
            levels.index = (levels.chosen+1);
        } else {
            levels.index++;
        }
        $(".container-folders").css('width', (container = (container+325)) + 'px');
        **$(".container-folders").animate( { right: slide = (levels.index < 1) ? 325 : (slide+325) }, 250);**
        get_folders_hierarchy(folders);
    })
    function get_folders_hierarchy (folders) {
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "folders/jq_get_folders_hierarchy/" + folders.chosen,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (element) {
                $("div.container-folders").append('<div class="container-folder"><a name="level-' + levels.index + '"></a><ul id="folders-hierarchy-' + folders.chosen + '" data-levels="' + levels.index + '">');
                if (element!=null) {
                    for (var i=0;i<element.length;i++) {
                        $("#folders-hierarchy-" + folders.chosen).append('<li><input type="radio" value="' + element[i].child + '" name="folders[]" /><a href="#level-' + (levels.index+1) + '" data-folder="' + element[i].child + '">' + element[i].name + '</a></li>');
                        if (i==(element.length)-1) {
                            folders.chosen = element[i].parent;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $("#folders-hierarchy-" + folders.chosen).append('<li><input type="radio" value="' + folders.chosen + '" name="folders[]" />Choose this Folder</li>');
                }
                $("div.container-folders").append('</ul></div>');
            }
        });
    }
    get_folders_hierarchy(folders);
});
```

I suspect it's a float or something, but I just can't see which, where, or — more importantly — why.

Also, [here's the code](http://jsfiddle.net/WayneSmallman/czUbZ/1/). However, due to how the data is assembled, it's not practical to supply JSON data.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle please?

Comment: Derek, I've added a link to the opening topic. However, I can't supply any JSON data; it's just too complex to dig out all of the folder data for all of the different folders and their subordinates.

Comment: I, too, created that fiddle, by copying and pasting your code. But it's missing too much to be of any use in debugging, which is why I asked for something.